# validation combination date from between date to same like time same like day

Tags: php, laravel

column date from, date to and time from and time to and days.
I want to check when a new entry is not same and not between.. like

```
id    date from        date to       time from     time to         day
1    29-5- 2018        10-5-2018     10:00         5:00            Mon,Tue
2    6 -6- 2018        10-6-2018     10:00         5:00            Mon,tue
```

like this second entry not right so I want duplicate validation for this.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: down vote
favorite
column date from, date to and time from and time to and days. I want to check when a new entry is not same and not between.. like

id   date_from     date_to   time_from time_to   day                                                 1    29-5- 2018  10-5-2018 10:00     5:00          Mon,Tue                                       
 2   6 -6- 2018   10-6-2018  2:00      3:00        Mon,tue

Answer (score 0):

If you use Carbon library it is easy.

Carbon doc page (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) has a nice example for between:

```
$from = Carbon::create(2018, 5, 29, 10);
$to = Carbon::create(2018, 5, 10, 17);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2018, 5, 29, 10)->between($from, $to, false));   // bool(false)
```